# C# - Getting record from a row using DataRow

Tags: c#, row, record, datarow

I'm trying to get record of a row using DataRow. Here's what I've done so far:

```
 uID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
 PhotoDataSetTableAdapters.MembersTableAdapter mem = new PhotoDataSetTableAdapters.MembersTableAdapter();
 PhotoDataSet.MembersDataTable memTable = mem.GetMemberByID(uID);
 DataRow[] dr = memTable.Select("userID = uID");
 string uName = dr["username"].ToString();
```

Then I got the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

The error points to `"username"`. I don't know what's wrong because I'm just trying to assign a string variable to a string value. Anyone figures out the reason of the error? Please help and thanks.

Comment: Which types are `userID` and `uID` columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dr` is a `DataRow[]` not a `DataRow`, therefor the compiler complains that you pass a String when he needs an `int` for the index.

You actually want the username of the the single `DataRow` in the `DataTable`, am i right?

```
String uName = memTable.AsEnumerable().Single().Field<String>("username");
```

Note that this throws an exception if there is more than one row in the `DataTable`. But since you pass an ID to the `DataAdapter`, i assume that it should return only one record.

Comment: The problem is in the query, when it's executed.

Comment: @ivowiblo: No, the problem is that OP actually has a DataTable with one DataRow since he passes the id already to the DataAdapter. Hence the `Select` seems to be redundant. He just needs to take the `username` field of the first/single row.

Comment: That's exactly the reason, thank you for the explanation too.

Answer (score 4):

Change the following statement

```
DataRow[] dr = memTable.Select("userID = uID");
```

To

```
DataRow[] dr = memTable.Select("userID = "+ uID);
```

Comment: The problem is that the query is trying to compare the userID column with the "uID" string. You need to create an expression including the value of the uID. So, it uID = 4, the expression will be "userID = 4". This will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But the error has nothing to do with it doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are two problems. One is as Asif suggest that uID should be "userId = " + uID (should probably cast uID as string) and that dr is an array of datarows as Tim points out. You can access it by index too: dr[0]["userName"].ToString()